# Split string based on different "keywords" in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have a string in PHP:

```
$haystack = "[:something 1]Here is something 1 content[:something 2]here is something else[:something completely different]Here is the completely different content"
```

And it can continue forever.

So, I need to split them into an associative array:

```
$final_array = [
   'something 1' => 'Here is something 1 content',
   'something 2' => 'here is something else',
   'something completely different' => 'Here is the completely different content'
]
```

The only thing that is set is the beginning `[:` and then the end `]` The keyword can be a whole sentence with spaces etc.

How to do this?

Comment: show your code , what you try ..

Comment: Using Regular expression matches: Look at PREG_MATCH_ALL()

Comment: What have you tried? Please post some sample data and code, and tell us what isn't working for you. Also, check this link out: stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$str = "Hello world. It's a beautiful day.";
$main_array = explode("[:",$haystack);
foreach($main_array as $val)
{
    $temp_array = explode("]",$val);
    $new_array[$temp_array[0]] =  $temp_array[1];
}
print_r(array_filter($new_array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `explode` to split your strig up. like so:

```
     $haystack = "[:something 1]Here is something 1 content[:something 2]here is something else[:something completely different]Here is the completely different content";

    // Explode by the start delimeter to give us 
    // the key=>value pairs as strings
    $temp = explode('[:', $haystack);
    unset($temp[0]); // Unset the first, empty, value
    $results= []; // Create an array to store our results in

    foreach ($temp as $t) { // Foreach key=>value line
        $line = explode(']', $t); // Explode by the end delimeter
        $results[$line[0]] = end($line); // Add the results to our results array
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$haystack = "[:something 1]Here is something 1 content[:something 2]here is something else[:something completely different]Here is the completely different content";
$arr = preg_split('/\[:(.+?)\]/', $haystack, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$res = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i += 2) {
    $res[$arr[$i]] = $arr[$i+1];
}
print_r($res);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [something 1] => Here is something 1 content
    [something 2] => here is something else
    [something completely different] => Here is the completely different content
)
```

Comment: I love everything about this one except for the `.+?` -- I'd rather see a negated character class for performance reasons.